# Xamarin Forms change mainpage ios error

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin.Forms MasterDetailPage and ContentPage with Navigataion.
When app is started I call LoginPage

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginInPage());
```

Then logging in is success I call MasterDetailPage

```
App.Current.MainPage = new RootPage();
await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

In Android all work is well, but in iOS simulator has error

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

in Main.cs on ios

```
UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work.

```
 if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new Source.Pages.MenuPage();
                else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Source.Pages.MenuPage());
```